# How do I typeset fractions that include variables with both superscripts and subscripts?

Tags: lyx, subscripts, superscripts, fractions

I need to typeset the following equation. I am using Lyx, but I can't find anything in its math menu that can handle it. I think I will need to typeset the whole equation using ERT.

[image: Eq w super/subscripts]

Comment: Ah, Lyx.  With LaTeX it is just \frac{x^2_S}{R^2_\oplus} ...

Comment: @John It's (or can be) same with LyX. Ctrl+M, then start typing \fract x^2_S tab R^2_\oplus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No problem in LyX:

[image]

Sequence:

- Insert > Math > Display Formula
- In the math menu, insert a "standard fraction" [image]
- Type the base (say `x`) and insert a superscript [image]
- Return the cursor to the right of the base and insert a subscript [image]
- Do the same for the denominator and copy-and-paste the fraction. Change the base values as needed.
- You need `\oplus` for the operator

  [image]